# How can I summarize age ranges and counts in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I have  a table with a long list of individuals, and their age.  From this data, I was able to derive a list of all ages, and then count how many people were of each age.  Here is some simple, sample data and the current output.

**Raw Data**

```
---------------
| ID   | Age  |
---------------
   1      1
   2      5
   3      10
   4      1
   5      6
   6      3
   7      1
   8      5
   ... and so on.
```

**Summarized Output**

```
---------------
| Age | Count |
---------------
  1      13
  2      5
  3      2
    ....
  58     5
  59     2
  60     7
```

What I would like to do with the above, summarized data is further summarize it in groups of 5.  For instance, I want to find the total number of 1-5 year olds, 6-10 year olds, 11-15 year olds, etc., etc., like the sample data provided below.

```
---------------------
| Age Range | Count |
---------------------
  1-5          48
  6-10         35
  11-15        40
        ...
  46-50        25
  51-55        19
  56+          17
```

Is there an integrated, summarization feature that can do this, or will I need to group and summarize this numerical data myself?  If there isn't a straight goal for my request, my end result is to display a bar chart of these age ranges, because showing a graph for each age is just to much.  Instead of 60+ bars, I'd rather have around 10.  Can that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method 1: New field and use pivot table

Add a new column to your data with the following filled down.

```
=INT((B2-1)/5)*5+1&"-"&(INT((B2-1)/5)+1)*5
```

Or better yet, use this formula that will give you that "56+" category you asked for:

```
=IF(B2>55,"56+",INT((B2-1)/5)*5+1&"-"&(INT((B2-1)/5)+1)*5)
```

You can get the summary you want easily with a pivot table. Add the new field `AgeRange` to Row Labels and `Count of ID` to Values.

[image]

### Method 2: Use `FREQUENCY` function to build histogram

Make a column of upper bounds on the age ranges you want to plot, i.e., {5, 10, ..., 55}. Select the cells in the adjacent column, going one cell beyond the bottom row of your Upper Bounds. Without changing the selection, paste the following into the formula bar and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=FREQUENCY(B2:B101,E2:E12)
```

Where, `B2:B101` are your column of ages, and `E2:E12` are your column of Upper bounds.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Pivot table for sure!

Comment: Excellent, the `FREQUENCY` function was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't exactly what you are looking for but assuming that ID and Age are in column A & B respectively. Place the following formulate in C2

```
=IF(AND($B2<E$1,$B2>=D$1),1,0)
```

Place your age delimiters in row 1.

Sum the resulting values to get your numbers to graph.